# Cuda Tensor Cores: What is the effect of NumBlocks and ThreadsPerBlock?

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication, cuda-wmma

I am wondering what the effect of NumBlocks and ThreadsPerBlock on this simple matrix multiplication routine is

```
__global__ void wmma_matrix_mult(half *a, half *b, half *out) {

   // Declare the fragments
   wmma::fragment<wmma::matrix_a, M, N, K, half, wmma::row_major> a_frag;
   wmma::fragment<wmma::matrix_b, M, N, K, half, wmma::row_major> b_frag;
   wmma::fragment<wmma::accumulator, M, N, K, half> c_frag;

   // Initialize the output to zero
   wmma::fill_fragment(c_frag, 0.0f);

   // Load the inputs
   wmma::load_matrix_sync(a_frag, a, N);
   wmma::load_matrix_sync(b_frag, b, N);

   // Perform the matrix multiplication
   wmma::mma_sync(c_frag, a_frag, b_frag, c_frag);

   // Store the output
   wmma::store_matrix_sync(out, c_frag, N, wmma::mem_row_major);
}
```

Calling

```
`wmma_matrix_mult<<1, 1>>`: Incorrect
`wmma_matrix_mult<<1, 2>>`: Incorrect
`wmma_matrix_mult<<1, 4>>`: Incorrect
`wmma_matrix_mult<<1, 8>>`: Incorrect
`wmma_matrix_mult<<1, 16>>`: Incorrect
`wmma_matrix_mult<<1, 32>>`: Correct
```

Why does the number of threads per block even matter if every thread is doing then same execution? As you can see, I am not doing anything with `threadIdx.x` inside the kernel.

Comment: For Tensor cores all 32 threads of a warp cooperate. They have to call the tensor operations at the same time. Each thread does a different part of the matrix multiplication and of loading the operands and results. Internally the source data is exchanged and distributed between the threads.

Comment: "if every thread is doing then same execution" <- Threads/lanes always run *the same code* but with *different data* - resulting in a *different execution*. That's true for WMMA as it is for all work in CUDA.

Comment: Just for completeness. There are at least two exceptions (but not for tensor cores/WMMA here), when executing on the same data makes a difference: 1) Some load operations benefit from loading the same memory index (-> not exhibiting bank conflicts for shared memory, although loading from the same bank). 2) The Turing architecture introduced the uniform datapath and registers, which is (very very roughly) like a 33th lane for integer instructions only, which is shared between all the other 32 lanes. It is often used for common indices or loops. It has its own SASS instructions. @einpoklum

Comment: @Sebastian: Hmm... can you link to someplace describing this architectural feature? (And I was there were actual online resources on SASS, too...)

Comment: @einpoklum You mean the Uniform Datapath UDP with Uniform Register File URF? There is not much documentation. The SASS instructions are listed (only without details) in https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html (Cuda Binary Utilities Documentation). The Hot Chips presentation on pages 8 and 10 (https://old.hotchips.org/hc31/HC31_2.12_NVIDIA_final.pdf). Here in chapter 3.5.2 https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.07486.pdf The UDP SASS instructions are interspersed with other SASS instructions. So the compiler decides, what goes there. It improves throughput and frees regular registers.

Comment: The Hot Chips slide shows a Sub-Core or aka. SM Partition. With up to 32 warps per SM and up to 8 warps per SM Partition, one always gets the 'full' 64 URF 4 byte registers regardless of the block size in threads. However, it is also not possible to use more than 64 URF registers. There are a few mixed instructions to transfer data to and from UDP, some commands for indexing memory and it can be used for control flow instructions.

Comment: IIRC there was a scientific paper suggesting and estimating the improvement potential of an uniform datapath, shortly before it was implemented in Turing.

Comment: The paper is: Jatala, V., Anantpur, J., & Karkare, A. (2016). Improving GPU Performance Through Resource Sharing. Proceedings of the 25th ACM International Symposium on High-Performance Parallel and Distributed Computing - HPDC ’16. doi:10.1145/2907294.2907298

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tensor core operations](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma) happen at the [warp](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#simt-architecture) level.  The **w** in wmma signifies that.  Referring to [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#wmma):

> This requires co-operation from all threads in a warp.

Each tensorcore unit can accept one matrix multiply operation (i.e. `wmma::mma_sync`), from a warp, per clock cycle.

This means that a full warp (32 threads) must be available and participating, for the operation to make any sense (i.e. to be legal).  All of the `wmma::` operations are *collective* ops, which means that an entire warp is expected to be executing them, and is necessary for correct usage.

If you have multiple warps participating (e.g. a threadblock size of 64, or 128, etc.), you are effectively asking for multiple operations to be done, just like any other CUDA code.

Like any other CUDA code, launching an operation with multiple blocks is just a way to scale up the work being done, and of course is necessary if you want to engage the resources of a GPU that has multiple SMs.  Since tensorcore  units are a per-SM resource, this would be necessary to witness a CUDA GPU delivering anything approaching its full rated throughput for tensorcore ops.

> Why does the number of threads per block even matter if every thread is doing then same execution?

Every thread is not doing the same thing.  The `wmma::` collective ops are hiding [code under the hood that is specializing thread behavior according to which warp lane it belongs to](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#warp-level-matrix-instructions-for-mma).  For example, the thread in warp lane 0 will select different elements of the fragment to associate with (i.e. load, store) than any thread in any other warp lane.